# O label do checkbox deve estar à direita ou esquerda do controle?

Tags: checkbox, ux, entrada-de-dados

Geralmente colocamos o *label* à esquerda do controle de entrada de dados. Bom, tem *layouts* diferentes, mas esse é um bem comum. Por linearidade seria o caso do *label* continuar à esquerda. Mas é muito comum vermos o *label* ser colocado à direita. É verdade que nesses casos o *checkbox* não faz parte de uma sequência de campos de entrada de dados.

Não fica estranho hora estar de um lado, hora estar de outro? Pensando nesses dois cenários:

- um deles é um formulário de preenchimento onde um ou mais campos são *checkboxes*;
- o outro cenário onde esses *checkboxes* sejam apenas opções isoladas.

Quando usar o *label* de um lado e de outro? E o mais importante, por que deve ser assim?

Preciso de um justificativa plausível e não apenas uma opinião, se possível alguma referência que confirme.

Comment: boa discussão, tbm me preocupei com isso qdo estava fazendo o sistema.
Optei por colocar o texto á direita pq vindo a opção antes do texto meio que vc obriga o usuário a pensar, enquanto que se o texto vier antes e o usuario estiver desatento ele pode correr o olho pelo texto e marcar ou não indevidamente...
Se vc chega e pergunta "qual sua escolha?" imediatamente a pessoa vai se questionar escolha do que?...
Não sei se fui claro...acho que seria algo do tipo: escolha, e depois o texto, é mais lógico...ao contrário de dar a resposta e pedir que escolha depois....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um *checkbox* (caixa de seleção) representa uma opção binária que pode ser marcada ou desmarcada pelo usuário. Desse modo, muitíssimo mais importante do que a organização do texto que o acompanha é a [*affordance*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance) dele como opção selecionável: o usuário precisa primeiro entender que se trata de uma opção que pode ser marcada ou desmarcada.

Já o texto, ou rótulo, precisa ser claramente perceptível como relacionado à opção, para que não haja dúvidas sobre o que se está optando. Isso geralmente é feito mantendo-se esse rótulo suficientemente próximo da caixa e nas mesmas cores e dimensões.

O posicionamento do texto em relação à caixa costuma ser feito à direita ou acima dela, o que muito provavelmente *é uma convenção* (eu digo provavelmente porque não achei fontes comprobatórias para ter certeza absoluta). Quando questionários começaram a ser usados em estudos de sociologia e psicologia (mais ou menos quando a [escala Likert](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escala_Likert) foi criada, isto é, por volta do começo do século passado), provavelmente essa convenção foi utilizada porque auxilia na usabilidade em idiomas que são lidos da esquerda para a direita.

Ao colocar a caixa antes do texto e próxima a ele, se garante que a percepção de relação vai ser a melhor possível. Por exemplo, em um questionário contendo dezenas de perguntas, o texto de cada pergunta deve ter comprimentos diferentes. A colocação das caixas após o texto iria fazer com que as opções ficassem verticalmente desalinhadas, o que além de visualmente incômodo também dificultaria a fácil percepção da relação entre o texto e a caixa de cada pergunta.

No caso de um sistema computacional, esse princípio deveria ser seguido se também forem utilizadas grandes quantidades de opções em uma mesma tela. A percepção de relação pode também ser efetuada por espaçamento, ao se colocar diferentes opções (com seus respectivos textos) longe umas das outras. De todas as formas, o melhor a se fazer é certamente **seguir a convenção do sistema operacional** que se está utilizando. Além de provavelmente isso já ter sido estudado pelos desenvolvedores do SO, os usuários já estarão acostumados à essa convenção de forma que se evitará equívocos.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**

Quem escolhe é o cliente, quem projetou o layout ou a necessidade.

E o caso de línguas onde a escrita vem da direita para a esquerda.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Creio que há regras que devem ser quebradas, para manter a "*affordance*" !

Pode haver teorias sobre layout intuitivo, ou o modo de leitura do usuário, entretanto, vamos e convenhamos, não deve haver essa obrigatoriedade.

Os controles de formulário tem automaticamente um `label` associado a eles através do atributo `value`, entretanto aqueles que não possuem (text fields, checkboxes, radio buttons, e menus) possuem o atributo `for` que fará a referência para o controle.

Ou seja se eu quiser colocar o label em cima, em baixo, sobreposto, na diagonal, eu posso ! Não há um validador que dirá que está errado.

Não há uma justificativa fora o design. Existe cenário para o uso em todas as posições.

Exemplos :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No mais não é um padrão é pura teoria.

Embora seja dito [aqui(W3.org)](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G162.html) que o checkbox a nível de previsibilidade, deva ter o controle antes do label, ainda não deixa de ser uma opinião do que é melhor em termos de UX, entretanto ainda assim prevalece o design, esse por sua vez dirá o que é correto para determinado fim.

Imagine uma coluna de texto a esquerda e no centro outra com opções de checkbox, se seguir a "regra" acima o controle ficará entre 2 textos, e aí ? Fica mais legível ? Não, então depende do design.

```css
section{float:left;}
```

```html
<section>
blablbalbalballballlballbal<br>
blablbalbalballballlballbal<br>
blablbalbalballballlballbal<br>
blablbalbalballballlballbal<br>
blablbalbalballballlballbal<br>
</section>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
<label for="check">blablablalballbalbla</label>
```

Veja o resultado, é uma regra consistente ?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54614/discussion-on-answer-by-magichat-o-label-do-checkbox-deve-estar-a-direita-ou-esq)

Answer (score 0):

Essa pergunta incide muito sobre opinião, mas, tratando-se de UX, o conceito mais aceito diz que o Label deve estar a direita do controle. Com os mais diversos motivos:

- Alinhamento consistente;
- Acompanhar o nosso modo natural de leitura esquerda-direita;
- Ser consistente também com *labels* de tamanhos diversos.

Muito mais pode ser lido aqui (em Inglês): https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5080/should-checkbox-labels-be-to-the-right-or-the-left